# JavaScript RegEx to determine the email's domain (yahoo.com for example)

Tags: javascript, regex

With JavaScript I want to take a input
1st validate that the email is valid (I solved for this)
2nd, validate that the email address came from yahoo.com

Anyone know of a Regex that will deliver the domain?

thxs

Comment: Please show a complete E2E example if possible

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
var myemail = 'test@yahoo.com'

if (/@yahoo.com\s*$/.test(myemail)) {
   console.log("it ends in @yahoo");
}
```

is true if the string ends in `@yahoo.com` (plus optional whitespace).

Comment: I will add uppercase control for extra compatibility. Users might write "Yahoo.com" which is the same as "yahoo.com" when sending mails but not for javascript.

Answer (score 10):

You do not need to use regex for this.

You can see if a string contains another string using the `indexOf` method.

```
var idx = emailAddress.indexOf('@yahoo.com');
if (idx > -1) {
  // true if the address contains yahoo.com
}
```

We can take advantage of `slice()` to implement "ends with" like so:

```
var idx = emailAddress.lastIndexOf('@');
if (idx > -1 && emailAddress.slice(idx + 1) === 'yahoo.com') {
  // true if the address ends with yahoo.com
}
```

In evergreen browsers, you can use the built in [String.prototype.endsWith()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith) like so:

```
if (emailAddress.endsWith('@yahoo.com')) {
    // true if the address ends with yahoo.com
}
```

See the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith) for browser support.

Comment: @nobosh that's because there is no statement after the `if`. styfle has shown you how to test if yahoo.com is in the string - you supply what happens after that.

Comment: you need slice(idx+1), slice(idx) returns @yahoo.com

Answer (score 3):

```
function emailDomainCheck(email, domain)
{
    var parts = email.split('@');
    if (parts.length === 2) {
        if (parts[1] === domain) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

:)

Answer (score 2):

To check for a particular domain (yahoo.com):

```
/^[^@\s]+@yahoo.com$/i.test(email)
// returns true if it matches
```

To extract the domain part and check it later:

```
x = email.match(/^[^@\s]+@([^@\s])+$/)
// x[0] contains the domain name
```

Comment: Sorry, I mixed up the call to `match`. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

```
var rx = /^([\w\.]+)@([\w\.]+)$/;
var match = rx.exec("user@yahoo.com");
if(match[1] == "yahoo.com"){
 do something
}
```

second capturing group will contain the domain.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\yahoo.com/.test("you@yahoo.com"); //Returns True
/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\yahoo.com/.test("you@abc@yahoo.com"); //Returns false
/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\yahoo.com/.test("you#abc@yahoo.com"); //Returns false
/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\yahoo.com/.test("you/abc@yahoo.com"); //Returns false
```

Above are some test cases.

Answer (score 1):

*Domain name is mandatory like .com , .in , .uk It'll check update 2 letter after '.' and '@' is also mandatory.*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <script>
    function validateEmail(email) {
        debugger;
        console.log(email);
        var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
        //return ture for .com , .in , .co  upto 2 letter after .
        console.log(re.test(String(email).toLowerCase()));
        return re.test(String(email).toLowerCase());
    }
    </script>

    <h2>Text field</h2>
    <p>The <strong>input type="text"</strong> defines a one-line text input field:</p>

    <form action="#" onSubmit="validateEmail(firstname.value)">
    First name:<br>
    <input type="email" name="firstname">
    <br>
    Last name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="lastname">
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit">
    </form>

    <p>Note that the form itself is not visible.</p>
    <p>Also note that the default width of a text field is 20 characters.</p>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

After reading previous answers and checking https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_string_endswith, the simplest way to check domain of an email is `String.prototype.endsWith()` method.

A simple program to check different inputs can be like below:

```js
function validateEmail(email: string): boolean {
    return email.endsWith("example.com");
}

const emailCheckResults = new Map<string, boolean>();

const emailsToCheck = ["test@example.com", "example.com@somethingelse.com", "attacker@somedomain.com"];
emailsToCheck.map((email) => {
    emailCheckResults.set(email, validateEmail(email));
});

Array.from(emailCheckResults.keys()).map((key) => {
    console.log(`Checked: ${key}, Result: ${emailCheckResults.get(key)}`);
});
```

This will result following:

```
Checked: test@example.com, Result: true
Checked: example.com@somethingelse.com, Result: false
Checked: attacker@somedomain.com, Result: false
```

Approaches like using `indexOf` or `split` simply didn't seem to me clean.

I recommend using `String.prototype.endsWith()` method to avoid simple mistakes in regex, to improve readability and testability of the code, to reduce attack surface if this is used in an authentication system etc.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//EN">
<html>
  <head>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    var okd = ['yahoo.com'] // Valid domains...

    var emailRE = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._+-]+@([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$/

    function ckEmail(tst)
    {  
      var aLst = emailRE.exec(tst)
      if (!aLst) return 'A valid e-mail address is requred';
      var sLst = aLst[1].toLowerCase()
      for (var i = 0; i < okd.length; i++) {
          if (sLst == okd[i]) {
              return true
          }
      }

      return aLst[1];
    }

    var ckValid = ckEmail(prompt('Enter your email address:'))

    if (ckValid === true) {
        alert(ckValid)  // placeholder for process validated
    } else {
        alert(ckValid)  // placeholder for show error message
    }

    </script>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> String(​'test@yahoo.com').replace​​​​​​​​(/^[^@]*@/, '')
'yahoo.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

For Yahoo domains (without username)

```
@(((qc|ca)?\.yahoo\.com)|yahoo\.(com(\.(ar|au|br|co|hr|hk|my|mx|ph|sg|tw|tr|vn))?|ae|at|ch|es|fr|be|co\.(in|id|il|jp|nz|za|th|uk)|cz|dk|fi|de|gr|hu|in|ie|it|nl|no|pl|pt|ro|ru|se))
```