# Email validation for specific domain name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following form. I want to validate the email field .it should only contain for domain name "**@somename.com** " when the user clicks submit.

The mail should only be validated when the check box is clicked to show the email field.

If the email is invalid i want to prevent submission

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="rForm" data-toggle="validator" role="form">

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-8">
                                <label class="checkbox-inline col-xs-10">
                                    <input type="checkbox" ID="chkbx"> Email 
                                </label>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group email">
                            <div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-8">

                                <div class="col-xs-8">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control "  placeholder="Enter email">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-8">
                                <input type="reset" class="btn btn-default" id="rset" value="Reset">
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" value="Submit">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

JS

```
 $("#submit").on('keypress click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
$('#chkbx').hide();
$('#chkbx').click(function () {
       // This will show / hide your element accordingly
       $('.email').toggle();
});


    });
```

Comment: So look to see if the text is there with indexOf or a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [JavaScript RegEx to determine the email's domain (yahoo.com for example)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270185/javascript-regex-to-determine-the-emails-domain-yahoo-com-for-example). You can use that and augment your example:

```js
$('#chkbx').click(function() {
  // This will show / hide your element accordingly
  $('.email').toggle();
});


$("#submit").on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($('#chkbx').is(':checked')) {
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270185/javascript-regex-to-determine-the-emails-domain-yahoo-com-for-example
    console.log(/@testdomain.com\s*$/.test($('#email_input').val()));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-horizontal" id="rForm" data-toggle="validator" role="form">

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-8">
      <label class="checkbox-inline col-xs-10">
        <input type="checkbox" ID="chkbx" checked>Email
      </label>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="form-group email">
    <div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-8">

      <div class="col-xs-8">
        <input id="email_input" type="text" class="form-control " placeholder="Enter email">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-8">
      <input type="reset" class="btn btn-default" id="rset" value="Reset">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Not sure why you'd allow trailing spaces in an email address.

Comment: I can't think of any use cases off of the top of my head other than convenience for accepting user input, but you could simply trim the value of course or remove the whitespace and quantifier characters from the regular expession

Answer (score -1):

Use the following function to test for your email.
EDIT:

You first need to add a `name=` and `id=` to your email input field.... So what you want to do is:

`<input type="text" class="form-control "  placeholder="Enter email" name="email" id="email">`

and then do:

```
function testEmail(string) {
    var regex = /.+@somename.com$/i;
    return regex.test(string);
}

//testEmail("nope@test.com"); // false
//testEmail("what@somename.com.other"); //false
//testEmail("yeah@somename.com"); //true
//testEmail("@somename.com"); // false

$('form').submit(function(e){
    var values = $('form').serialize();
    if(!testEmail(values.email)) 
        e.preventDefault();
    // your submission code goes here.
})
```